# Javascript how to restart timer

Tags: javascript, timer

I borrowed the following code to get 5sec timer working. Now i need to be able to hit the play button to restart the timer.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="rightCol">
        <span id="countdown" class="timer"> </span>
        <div>
            <textarea name="passage" id="passage_text"></textarea>
            <input type="button" id="passage_button" value="Publish">
            <input type="button" value="Play" id="play">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript function:**

```
var seconds = 5;
function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Time's Up!";
                document.getElementById("passage_text").disabled = true;

    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}
 
var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
```

Right now I've got the `play` button refreshing the page but there must be a better way to do this. I'm not very JS savvy so some help is appreciated. jQuery is acceptable.

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't just `calling the function` with your `button`? That will reset all of the variables to their base values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset the value when the button is clicked;

```
<input type="button" value="Play" id="play" onclick="javascript:seconds=5;">
```